# mootools | Hide and show animation

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, mootools

I have a mootools code:

```
(function() {
    var index = 0;
    Element.implement({
       toggle: function() {
        var args = Array.slice(arguments, 0);
        count = args.length - 1;
        return this.addEvent("click", function() {
               args[index].apply(this, arguments);
           index = (count > index) ? index + 1 : 0;
        });
    },
    resetToggle: function() {
       index = 0;
    }
    });
})();

document.getElement(".toggle").toggle(
    function() {
       document.id("menu").setStyle("display", "block");
    }, function() { 
       document.id("menu").setStyle("display", "none");
    }
    );
});
```

How to hide/show div.menu container with animation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

haha this looks like my old toggle code :) do:

```
document.id('menu').setStyles({
    display: 'block',
    opacity: 0
}).fade(1);
```

and the opposite.

update to:

```
(function(){
    var Element = this.Element,
        Elements = this.Elements;

    [Element, Elements].invoke('implement', {
        toggle: function(){
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments), 
                count = args.length-1,
                // start at 0
                index = 0;

            return this.addEvent('click', function(){
                var fn = args[index];
                typeof fn === 'function' && fn.apply(this, arguments);
                // loop args.
                index = count > index ? index+1 : 0;
            });
        }
    });

}());
```

Comment: Answered at same time! And as usual your answer beats mine :) `+1`

Comment: And your solution without animation like in Sergio's example?

Comment: sergio's example is via mootools-more (Fx.Reveal) - I tried to keep it confined to mootools-core. the old version of the toggler has an issue - the `index` is shared in the closure so if you have more than 1 element using a toggler, they will interfere with each other. you can morph any css properties with Fx.morph from -core as well. check http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx.Morph and change the effect.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a animation you could use [reveal()](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Reveal#Fx-Reveal%3areveal) / [dissolve()](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Reveal#Fx-Reveal%3adissolve) available in MooTools-More

```
document.getElement(".toggle").toggle(function () {
    document.id("menu").reveal();
}, function () {
    document.id("menu").dissolve();
});
```

Note you had a pair `});` too much in your code (last line)

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/W4eT9/)

But if you would use more, there is already a [.toggle()](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Reveal#Fx-Reveal%3atoggle) method you can use, that would give you just show/hide [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Z26fA/).